# Laravel Validation response via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.4

I am implementing AJAX based login using Laravel 5.4 authentication process.

I keep getting `422` responses, so after some research , I came up with this validation method in my `LoginController` (which overrides the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait method:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        $this->username() => 'required|email|max:50|unique:users',
        'nickname' => 'required|max:30|min:6|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        $responseBag = $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray();
        $responseBag['type'] = ['error'];

        if($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json($responseBag, 422);
        }

        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );

    }
}
```

I am expecting this response:

```
array:3 [
  "nickname" => array:1 [
    0 => "The nickname field is required."
  ]
  "password" => array:1 [
    0 => "The password confirmation does not match."
  ]
  "type" => array:1 [
    0 => "error"
  ]
]
```

But I get this response

```
{email: "These credentials do not match our records."}
```

If I `dd($messageBag)` before the response, then I get the expected result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the method definition for `LoginController:login`, [`$this->validateLogin`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L30) isn't returned and should not be.

`$this->validate` throws an exception which is handled accordingly for AJAX and normal requests when request validation fails.

You should write your validation as:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required|email|max:50|unique:users',
        'nickname' => 'required|max:30|min:6|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. If I `dd($request->ajax())` before the `if` statement it returns true. If I place the `dd` inside the `if` statement, it triggers, so it is getting to the `return JSON` statement. Also, I am using `jQuery` (V3, latest)  to `post` with `$.ajax` function. This has worked in prev. Laravel versions OK.